# SignalR Core Android client with JWT authintication returning NULL

Tags: java, android, asp.net-core, jwt, signalr

i'm building an android application that communicate with asp.net core signalR hub , every thing was good without the authentication, actually i cant figure it out. the is in Web APi and i use JWT for  authentication and send it back to android device as an access token, so how to send token to the hub??
i found in the documentation this code:

```
HubConnection hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("https://example.com/myhub")
.withAccessTokenProvider(Single.defer(() -> {
    // Your logic here.
    return Single.just("An Access Token");
})).build();
```

but i could not figure it!! what is the logic that  i should do??
also this is my provider class

```
public class MyCustomProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return connection.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

this is my hub

```
public class LocationHub : Hub
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ApplicationDbContext _Context { get; }

    public LocationHub(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _Context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task ShareLocation(double Latitude , double Longitude)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New location from: "+Context.UserIdentifier+"::"+ Latitude + "///" + Longitude);
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveNewLocation", Latitude, Longitude);
    }

    public override  Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var user = _Context.Users.Where(u => u.Email == Context.UserIdentifier).FirstOrDefault();
        user.LoginStatus = true;
        _Context.SaveChanges();
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

Context.UserIdentifier is Null !! when i try this

```
PreferencesStore.loadPreferences(this);
    String mToken = PreferencesStore.getToken();
    Log.d("SignalR", mToken);
    hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://myserver/locationhub")
            .withAccessTokenProvider(Single.defer(() -> {

                return Single.just(mToken);
            }))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

and Finally found the solution, i will put it here in case any one have this issue:

```
PreferencesStore.loadPreferences(this);
    String mToken = PreferencesStore.getToken();
    hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://myserver/locationhub")
            .withHeader("Authorization", mToken)
            .build();
```

its different than the documentation. right here i used `.withHeader("Authorization", mToken)` but its working just fine.